# Next image not being displayed on swipe in 'ImageSwitcher'

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, touch-event, swipe-gesture

I am really new to android development and I have been trying to create an Image gallery app. Everything is working fine except when I am swiping to display next or previous image, nothing is being displayed. How do I fix this?

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv_folder);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images,int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("abc",abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I got Nullpointerexeption in it. so i used

```
  try {
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = extras.getString("abc");

        Glide.with(FullImageActivity.this)
                .load(value)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false; // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })

                .into(images);
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And after 5 or 6 swipes i am able to view Images.As you asked in question that you are not able to view images,so the problem is that the thumbnail dont exist.As in my log for every non viewable thumbnail i get this error

`I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://media/external/images/thumbnails/11`

hope this might help.

ps : wait for toast to complete before next swipe for clearance.

Comment: I am still not able to view images even after 10 swipes, I updated my code according to your answer, and also I wasn't getting any exceptions before, there are other java files too which I haven't included in this question as the code which wasn't working for me was in this activity, still I have included one more java file now and updated my question. This activity is responsible for displaying thumbnails

Comment: Have you included this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to your manifest file.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
....I included that and all these permissions too

Comment: well I cant find issues when i run this code [Here](https://gist.github.com/SahdeepSingh/98b498e28c0d9ff42576b60bcc38e109) and it worked fine.   Also if you want more reference you can visit [here](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/02/add-gesture-in-image-switcher-to-swipe.html) and [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)